# Drupal 7 - method or correct procedure for globally updating content types - Advice/Suggestions needed

Tags: drupal

(I added this on the Drupal support forum also, hope that's ok :) Just hoping to get plenty off feedback)

I am not long after finishing my first major Drupal 7 build, which was really enjoyable but I would admit a rather large learning curve, which after over a year of development, I would admit I still don't know the full power and capacity of Drupal.

My build started off with building our own sub theme, and using that to overwrite all the core theme styles and tailor it to our needs.

Next, I will explain the structure our build.  I was tasked with approx 20 different page styles, so in turn I developed 20 content types(templates) for each of these different styles, from here I then added a number of key fields to each content type and then inputted my code into these fields within each content type. e.g. A page with a banner region, a slider region below and a content region below that, for this example say they are all 960px the width of our sites body.  So this content type would be made up of three fields, with the the div's and content added to each.

The node developer process would be, if the user wanted that above e.g. style of page, they would select that content type, and simply edit the demo content with the new nodes needed content and set live.  So this is the process of the site for developing pages, which has not hit a wall, sadly for me.

So my question is, would it be possible to have say a content type (Or suggest a better approach) which we could globally switch around the layout/styles which then would filter down to all the children nodes? or be able to assign nodes to different content types or anything along them lines? I did look at switching between subthemes for a specific content type, which on each of the subthemes would have different set .css styles but this could maybe get messy and quickly get out of control.

If you guys could give feedback on our build and how it compares to yours and how we could go about making more efficient that would mean a lot.

Guys, any help or suggestions at this time would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) three modules which help you lay out and/or modify content on a page. They are: [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels), [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context), and [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds). [Here's an amazing tutorial](http://buildamodule.com/) which walks you through each of them so you can get an idea of how they are used. Use the dropdown at the top-left side of the page to jump to "Advanced Site Building" and scroll down from there.